# Null Entry Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in my view:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Approve", "NewsApprove", New With {ID}, DBNull.Value)%>
```

in my controller:

```
Function NewsApprove(ByVal dID As Integer) As ActionResult
    dTempNews.ApproveNews(dID)
    Return RedirectToAction("Administrator")
End Function
```

My problem is that it always return an error that says:
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'dID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult NewsApprove(Int32)' in 'UC_Website.UserController'. To make a parameter optional its type should be either a reference type or a Nullable type.

But I don't see any problem with the code.
I think this is a simple problem but i can't figure out how to make it work..
Help please.
Thank you!

Comment: found the error..
there's a problem with the code:D
it's the parameter name..
hmmm, my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked on asp.net MVC. But, here is my understanding.

Look at the link that gets generated for `<%=Html.ActionLink("Approve", "NewsApprove", New With {ID}, DBNull.Value)%>`. Does it look like http://.../Approve/? (i.e without any ID parameter)

Either you should pass in a valid integral value for the action to execute. i.e the link should look like http://.../Approve/0123

For that, you should pass in a valid integral value & not null value.
It seems the code should be `new with {"dID", ID}`, I guess.

OR

Let the `NewsApprove` method accept `Nullable<int>` if a link without the ID parameter is fine.
(e.g. http://.../Approve/)

EDIT: Is the `NewsApprove` method overloaded? i.e 1 with an integer parameter & another method with same name, but no parameters.

Comment: it does return the right link
http://.../User/NewsApprove/1
but with error..i've put a breakpoint in the function but seems that it gives me the right link but doesn't pass through the function NewsApprove..

Comment: it's not overloaded..i think it should work even if it's not overloaded? :D

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Approve", "NewsApprove", New With {ID}, DBNull.Value)%>
```

Controller:

```
Function NewsApprove(ByVal ID As Integer) As ActionResult
    dTempNews.ApproveNews(ID)
    Return RedirectToAction("Administrator")
End Function
```

the parameter name should be the same as the name of the value you're trying to call..